# Blazor in Windows Forms App: Layout not loading

Tags: blazor, windows-forms-core

I am trying to host blazor inside a webview2 control in windows forms, But the layout that I designed does not load, so the page loads incorrectly, There is a LayoutEngine property in webview2 that I don't know how to set:

```
 BlazorWebView blazorWeather = new BlazorWebView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html",                    
                Services = serviceProvider,
                 LayoutEngine = 
            };
```

Is this the solution for this? and what value should I set to this?

Edit:

this is the code that adds webviews to Form1, when I add the layout only layout shows and when i add the component, it shows:

```
 using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            BlazorWebView blazorLayout = new BlazorWebView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html",
                Services = serviceProvider,

            };

            blazorLayout.RootComponents.Add<MainLayout>("#app");


            BlazorWebView blazorComponent = new BlazorWebView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html",                    
                Services = serviceProvider
            };
            
            blazorComponent.RootComponents.Add<CoronaVirus>("#app");
            var form1 = new Form1(); // serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Form1>();
            form1.Controls.Add(blazorLayout);
            form1.Controls.Add(blazorComponent);                
            Application.Run(form1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an App component like the default App in blazor and wrote this:

```
BlazorWebView blazorApp = new BlazorWebView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html",
                Services = serviceProvider,

            };
            blazorApp.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
```

And this solved my problem.

Edit:

A more correct answer is wraping the component markup in a layoutview:

```
<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
</LayoutView>
```